# Merging raster ARC GIS

Tags: merge, gis, arcgis, elevation, srtm

When I meerge 4 rasters of SRTM rasters into one by the mosaic to raster tool of ARC GIS pro. I get a raster with values from 0 to 250 when the values of original rasters were from -444 to 5034.
I tried many option, but every time the same problem.

Any solution?